Text overlap the image and align center with different digit number
without transform css:

Here is my original code:


.points-value {
  grid-template-columns: .1fr 2fr;
  .label {
    .points-img {
      height: 3em;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    p {
      transform: translate(-500%);
      z-index: 3;
    }
  }
}
<div class="info-row points-value">
  <span class="label">
        <img class="points-img" alt="" src="/vip-icon.png`}">
        <p>1</p>
   </span>
  <progress-bar></progress-bar>
</div>



for 1 digit number:

for 2 digit number:

How to make the text overlap the image and align center with different digit number?

The CSS does not look valid, or I just do not know this version. As SCSS it also does not look like it has a valid scope and there is no display:grid in there

I would simply position the text absolute above the image. And then give it the same width as the image, and simply center the text within that width.

I tried to recreate your screenshot, so this is more code than you need.
Important for you is that .points-value is display: grid and the .label is positioned in a cell.
I also centered the content of .label with display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; and put the number over the circle with position: absolute;


.points-value {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.label {
  display: flex;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.label .points-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.label p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

.points-value .progress-bar-wrapper {
  grid-column: 2;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translate(-10px);
  z-index: -3;
}

.points-value .progress-bar-background {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.points-value .progress {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 30%;
  height: 15px;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div class="info-row points-value">
  <span class="label">
    <p>1</p>
    <img class="points-img" alt="" src="https://www.textures4photoshop.com/tex/thumbs/solid-circle-png-thumb16.png">

  </span>
  <div class="progress-bar-wrapper">
    <span class="progress-bar-background" />
    <span class="progress" />
  </div>

</div>



